# How to create structured output forarray of objects by using StructuredOutputParser in langchain

Tags: python, json, openai-api, langchain

for normal type can create but for an array of objects i cant able to create proper structure

```
from langchain.output_parsers import ResponseSchema


id_schema = ResponseSchema(
    name="id",
    description="This is the id of the product",
    type= 'str'
)

title_schema = ResponseSchema(
    name="title",
    description="This is the title of the product",
    type= 'str'
)
```

how to create for variants

```
{
    "id": "gid://shopify/Product/8712555397421",
    "title": "Cocoa Butter Hydrating Lotion",
    "productType": "Lotion",
    "description": "Nourish and hydrate your skin with the richness of cocoa butter in our soothing lotion.",
    "handle": "himalaya-lotion-cocoa",
    "tags": [
        "cocoa butter",
        "hydrating",
        "skincare"
    ],
    "vendor": "Himalaya",
    "featuredImage": {
        "url": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0810/3949/1373/products/51HzgC8ytcL._SY606.jpg?v=1693296558"
    },
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/46838661447981",
            "sku": "HL5004",
            "title": "Default Title",
            "amount": "169.0",
            "url": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0810/3949/1373/products/51HzgC8ytcL._SY606.jpg?v=1693296558"
        }
    ]
}
```

I try with StructuredOutputParser with ResponseSchema and PydanticOutputParser